# All elements in string are lower

Tags: c++, string

Good evening guys! 
  To finish my BattleShip game I need a gameOver function that finds out if half of the chars of a string are lower. I mean, each string names a ship:
- For example, I have a ship represented by char P size 4 , his string status gonna be: PPPP.

Each time I attack the ship position the char I hit goes lower. Ship sinks when half is destroyed as in half of the chars are lower.

```
bool Ship::isDestroyed() const{

    int tam;
    tam = status.length();

    cout << tam;

    int i = 0;
    int lowercase;
    lowercase = 0;

    lowercase = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        if (islower(status[i])){
            lowercase++;
            cout << "lowercase" << lowercase << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "lowercase" << lowercase << endl;

    if (lowercase == tam / 2){
        cout << (int)tam / 2 << endl;
        cout << "lowercase fail" << lowercase << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool Board::gameOver() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ships.size() - 1; i++){
        if ((ships[i].isDestroyed())){
            return false;
            continue;
        }

    }
    cout << "GameOver" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

`ships.size()` - ships vector with Ship objects inside.

I guess the problem is with gameOver but I really can sort it out.

Comment: You should probably make your test if(lowercase <= tam/2), because sometimes it's impossible for exactly half the chars to be lowercase (e.g. if the ship is 5 chars long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function gameOver doesn't check all ships because the return statement:

```
if((ships[i].isDestroyed())){
        return false; // LOOK HERE!!! :(
        continue;
    }
```

You have to check that all ships are destroyed.

Solution:

I'd change your code for this:

```
#include <algorithm>  //for count_if()

bool islower(char a){
    if( tolower(a) == a ) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool Ship::isDestroyed() const{ 
    // This is not necessary(You can let your isDestroyed function without any changes)

    //This counts those chars that satisfy islower:
    int lowercase = count_if (status.begin(), status.end(), islower); 
    return ( lowercase <= (status.length/2) ) ? true : false;
}

bool Board::gameOver() {
    bool is_the_game_over = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ships.size() ; i++){
        if( ships[i].isDestroyed() == false ) { 
            //There is at least one ship that is not destroyed.
            is_the_game_over = false ;
            break;
        }
    }       
    return is_the_game_over;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to make an isLower function? @Emiliano Sangoi

Comment: Yes, you have to do it if you want to use count_if. There is a islower() function in the code that you posted. You can try this: bool islower(char a){ return a == tolower(a); }

Comment: Once `gameOver()` has found a ship that hasn't been destroyed, there's no need to keep looking whether other ships have been destroyed. It's perfectly OK to short circuit here. It's fine to use `std::find_if()` or `std::count_if()` instead of a loop. And don't forget that there is a `std::islower()` function (although it takes an `int` argument instead of a `char` and you need to pass it an `unsigned char` in any case, so you'll want to use a lambda or something like `bool is_lower(char c) { return std::islower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }`).

Comment: If you use `std::find_if` you'll want to find the first thing that's **not** a lowercase character.  So you'll probably want `bool not_lower(char c) { return !std::islower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }`.